# Selecting and modifying a field in SQL

Tags: sql

Let's say I have a table with name and birthday fields. I can use this SQL to return a table of items sharing the same birthday (e.g. 4 people have the birthday 4/8/1995):

```
SELECT DISTINCT "Birthday", COUNT("Birthday") as "FieldCount" 
FROM "test_main" Group BY "Birthday" Order By "FieldCount" DESC
```

But how can I modify the value that I select to ignore the year, e.g. get a count of birthdays by month, for example, Jan: 42 names, Feb: 28 names, etc

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use built in functions to extract the year and month:

```
SELECT month(birthday), count(*) as FieldCount
FROM test_main
Group BY month(birthday)
Order By FieldCount DESC;
```

Notes:

- There is no need for the `distinct` with a `group by`.
- You do not need to surround everything with double quotes.
- `COUNT(*)` should be find for what you want.

Comment: He said ignore year :)

Comment: @JohnWu: Still a better answer though

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT month(Birthday), COUNT(Birthday)
FROM test_main
Group BY month(Birthday) 
Order By COUNT(Birthday) DESC
```